# How to insert with a where from another database?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I insert using sql when my data is on one table and my where is on another. Here is the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_can (online_id) VALUES ('$online') WHERE user.online = 'online'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I seem to be getting errors when trying to insert, the insert does not happen. It looks like I am messing up with my where code. Does anybody know how I can insert my data?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing parts of one statement type with parts of another. The SQL needs to be something like:

```
INSERT INTO user_can (online_id) SELECT online_id FROM user WHERE online = 'online';
```

The `INSERT ... VALUES ...` format is for providing explicit values in the SQL. [Further Information about INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).